# How do I make this nodeJS HTTP proxy server an HTTPS proxy server?

Tags: node.js, http, https, proxy, node-http-proxy

I managed to make a proxy server in nodeJS that works for http requests (code below), but I want it to work with HTTPS web servers. I have a self-signed certificate. Is there any way I can modify this code to work with HTTPS web server?

```js
const http = require('http');
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
const url = require('url');

const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});

http.createServer((req, res) => {
  console.log('Original URL:', req.url);

  // Proxy the modified request to the target URL
  proxy.web(req, res, {
    target: "http://localhost:8000/hehelol",
    headers: req.headers,
  });
}).listen(3000);

console.log('Proxy server listening on port 3000');
```

Comment: use [```https```](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#httpscreateserveroptions-requestlistener) module ?